# wherenotin() must be of type array, null given error

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

so im trying to update my data, and it shows this:

Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings(): Argument #1 ($bindings) must be of type array, null given

so when i try to look into it, the error is here

```
        $tradeSetup->tags()->whereNotIn('user_tag_id', $request->userTag)->delete();
```

weird thing is, i already pass the value as array, but the error comes out when i dont want to return any userTag at all.

```
//form.blade.php

<div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">@lang('Tags')</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select name="userTag[]" class="select2-tag form-control" multiple="multiple">
                    @foreach($userTags as $key => $userTag)
                        <option value="{{ $userTag->id }}" {{ $tradeSetup->tags->where('user_tag_id',$userTag->id)->first() ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $userTag->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
    </div><!--form-group-->
```

```
//TradeSetup model

public function userTag()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserTag::class);
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Tag::class, 'taggable');
    }
```

```
//TradeSetupController.php

public function update(Request $request, TradeSetup $tradeSetup)
{
        $request->validate([
            'symbol' => 'required',
            'entry_price' => 'required',
            'target_price' => 'required',
            'stop_loss_price' => 'required',
            'notes' => 'required',
            // 'tags' => 'required',
            'side' => 'required',
            'confidence' => 'required',
            // 'ratio' => 'required',
        ]);


        $tradeSetups = $this->tradeSetupService->update($request, $tradeSetup);

        // dd($request->userTag);

        $tradeSetup->tags()->whereNotIn('user_tag_id', $request->userTag)->delete();

        foreach($request->userTag as $tag){
            if($tradeSetup->tags()->where('user_tag_id', $tag)->exists()){
            // if (Tag::where('user_tag_id', $tag )->exists()) {

            }else if (Tag::whereHas('userTag')->where('taggable_id', $tradeSetup->id)->where('taggable_type', 'App\Domains\TradeSetup\Models\TradeSetup')->get()){

                Tag::create([
                    'user_tag_id'=> $tag,
                    'taggable_type' => get_class($tradeSetups),
                    'taggable_id'=> $tradeSetups->id,
                    // 'type' => $request->type,
                    // 'state'=> $request->state,
                ]);
            }
        }


return redirect()->route('frontend.user.tradeSetup.index')->withFlashSuccess('TradeSetup updated');



}
```

i tried to `dd($request->userTag)` and the result is `null`

FYI, userTag is not required so the user can just not input any userTag when they store/update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

my mistake, but i dont need to actually change the `null` to `[]`. i just want to delete all the record in Tag.

```
if(isset($request->userTag)){
        $tradeSetup->tags()->whereNotIn('user_tag_id', $request->userTag)->delete();
    }else{
        $tradeSetup->tags()->delete();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u dont have tags `<form>` and `<input type="submit">` to send request into your controller. Must be an action to provide all request info.

If u want to do it dynamic, use `axios` or `XmlHttpRequest` in javascript to send request into controller.

It's not a solution, but also u can check csrf protection, there is full information about forms and their protection, check this out
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/csrf

Comment: actually, i will pass the form.blade into another blade file using `@include` so it works just fine for me. i just dont know what to next if the input is null

Comment: i mean, that if you have null inputs, it means that u don't have any requests, no one http request, need to do some kind of triggers (buttons 'submit), like input element or button with event listener

Comment: @harith check devtools, in section "Network" you can find all http requests  to/from your site. If you dont do some submit events, you dont have request

Comment: it's not a progress to include file into file, check that your request sends and router can identify him

Answer (score 0):

The method `whereNotIn` needs an array as second argument. Then no value is selected in your form, the request doesn't contain any data for userTag and so it is null and not an empty array.

But you can simply fix this by defining a default parameter for userTags for example like this:

```
$tradeSetup->tags()->whereNotIn('user_tag_id', $request->userTag ?: [])->delete();
```